# Adding Metabox Value Using the content filter

Tags: theme-development, metabox

I am able to show repeater metabox on index and single post .Now I want to show this using

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_slug_filter_the_content' );
```

My code to get meta value

```
<?php
$data = get_post_meta($post->ID,"repeatable_fields",true);
echo '<ul>';
if (count($data) > 0){
    foreach((array)$data as $p ){
        if (isset($p['name']) || isset($p['select'])|| isset($p['url'])){
            echo '<li>Number: '.$p['name'].' Description: '.$p['select'].' Price: '.$p['url'].'</li>';
        }
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I guess My code will be

```
function theme_slug_filter_the_content( $content ) {
$custom_content = 'YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE';
$custom_content .= $content;
return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_slug_filter_the_content' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this ?Hope this will work.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'cd_display_quote' );
function cd_display_quote( $content )
{   
// We only want this on single posts, bail if we're not in a single post
// if( !is_single() ) return $content;

// We're in the loop, so we can grab the $post variable
global $post;


$data = get_post_meta($post->ID,"repeatable_fields",true);
echo '<ul>';
if (count($data) > 0){
    foreach((array)$data as $p ){
        if (isset($p['name']) || isset($p['select'])|| isset($p['url'])){
            echo '<li>Number: '.$p['name'].' Description: '.$p['select'].' Price: '.$p['url'].'</li>';
        }
    }
}
echo '</ul>';

// Return the values: quote first, then the content
return $content;
 }
```